# How convert mongo standalone to a replica set on Windows 10?

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongo on windows, more precisely for use on WSL (ubuntu subsystem on Windows), I used it for pet project on JS, now I want to convert mongod to a set of replicas. How to do this on windows?

Comment: Have a look at [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)

Comment: yes,thx, problem was with hot it do on windows

Comment: It's the same, just the folder names are different. And services are started/stopped with the service manager (`services.msc`)

Answer (score 0):

so I solved it in 3 steps:

1. In cmd open path
   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
2. Run command

> mongod --port 27017 --dbpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data" --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
> 3. Run mongo shell and enter command
> rs.initiate()